# Android -no content is displaying arrayadapter there are no errors showing

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

No content is displaying in the Numbers Activity. i have been struggling with this for the past two days.I searched a lot and i didn't find anything.so only i am asking.

Here's my code.
**NumbersActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

    // Create a list of words
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

    words.add(new Word("one","lutti"));
    words.add(new Word("two","otikko"));
    words.add(new Word("three","tolokooosu"));
    words.add(new Word("four","oyyisa"));
    words.add(new Word("five","massokka"));
    words.add(new Word("six","temmokka"));
    words.add(new Word("seven","kenakaku"));
    words.add(new Word("eight","kawinta"));
    words.add(new Word("nine","woe"));
    words.add(new Word("ten","naaaache"));


    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,words);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

**activity_numbers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity"/>
```

**WordAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    public WordAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, int resource, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, resource, words);
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="lutti"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="one"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Word.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;


public class Word {
    private String mDefaultTranslation;
    private String mMiwokTranslation;

    public Word(String mDefaultTranslation, String mMiwokTranslation){
        this.mDefaultTranslation = mDefaultTranslation;
        this.mMiwokTranslation = mMiwokTranslation;
    }

    public String getDefaultTranslation(){
        return mDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getmMiwokTranslation(){
        return mMiwokTranslation;
    }
}
```

**And my screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You should first explain what you are trying to accomplish and then how. After thst you should tell what works and what does not work. Or what happens instead.  Do you really think we will dig through your code to find out? No. You should tell us at the start of your post.

Comment: Sorry,this is my first post,

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting data in **getView** method. first you need to create a variable of your custom  list in adapter then initialize it in **constructor** you are passing data but not setting anywhere in adatper. then set that data in getView method.
also you need to create a **viewholder** class for creating reference of textviews in your adapter

Comment: Hi.Thanks for replying.i'm a newbie i don't understand what you are saying.Could you tell what line should i add where.